# Make objects spawn correctly within different screen widths sizes unity

Tags: screen, unity-game-engine, spawning

I made my first game in Unity. It should be published to Android and iOS. Everything is working fine except the asteroids are cut off when I change the screen ratio to 9:18(Samsung S8, Lg G6...) The asteroids are being cut off because the spawn points are fixed to -2.4f to 2.4f. I tried various things but nothing worked...I was already told to use screen.width and then to make some logic but I have no idea how to make the logic so that it actually works.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCU0y.jpg)

Here is my code that is spawning the asteroid in scene: `Instantiate(asteroid1prefab, new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.4f, 2.4f), 6, 0), Quaternion.identity);`

Any kind of help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: I don't if you are the one who upvoted my answer (if yes, thanks). Just in case (since I see that you are new here), the good practice is to **accept** an answer if you consider it answered your question. See [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) how to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to replace your spawn range with a range based on the screen size.
For that you can project **viewport coordinates** to **world coordinates**

Quoting the doc:

> A viewport space point is normalized and relative to the Camera. The
>   bottom-left of the Camera is (0,0); the top-right is (1,1). The z
>   position is in world units from the Camera.

Use [Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html) with input (0, 0) and (1, 1) to get the world coordinates of the top right and bottom left points of your screen. These will allow you to set the proper range to spawn your objects

**EDIT:**

This should give you something that looks like

```
Vector3 bottomLeftWorld = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, camera.nearClipPlane));
Vector3 topRightWorld = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, camera.nearClipPlane));

Instantiate(asteroid1prefab, new Vector3(Random.Range(bottomLeftWorld.x, topRightWorld.x), topRightWorld.y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: Thank you very much you saved me a lot of nerves. I was trying to solve this problem 11 days and got nowhere.